# Changing state even when the react-tabs component is not selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with react tabs.

```
state = {
    tabIndex: 0
};
```

...

```
    <Tabs
                selectedIndex={variable ? variable : tabIndex}
                onSelect={index => this.setState({ tabIndex: index })}
              >
```

If a variable is not pass, the page opens in the tab 0. But some times I want to open in a specific tab, so I pass, for example, the `variable = 1`.  But I also wants to update the `tabIndex`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize the `state` with the passed prop (*`variable` in this example*) (if passed)

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const {
    variable = 0
  } = this.props;

  this.state = {
    tabIndex: variable
  };
}
```

and keep using it as

```
<Tabs
    selectedIndex={tabIndex}
    onSelect={index => this.setState({ tabIndex: index })}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

`tabIndex` in state of the component is updated by you onSelect.

Comment: yes, but when I pass variable=1, the page opens in that tab, I don't need to select the tab